# Please can someone give me a simple example of how to use System.Monitor in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I find System.Monitor very confusing, although I understand threading, locks, deadlocks, race conditions, dining philosophers and all that jazz.  Normally I use a ManualResetEvent() to do inter-thread co-ordination, but I know that that's a heavyweight kernel object, and that System.Monitor (Enter/Pulse, etc.) is much more efficient.  I've Googled and Googled but cannot find a sensible example.

I would be most grateful if the SO crew could explain this potentially wonderful construct to me :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a very simple example; the call to `Wait` releases the lock (allowing `Worker` to obtain it) and adds the `Main` thread to the lock-object's pending queue. `Worker` then obtains the lock, and calls `Pulse`: this moves the `Main` thread into the lock-object's ready queue. When `Worker` *releases* the lock, `Main` can resume work.

Note that `lock(obj) {...}` is just compiler-candy for `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit` in a try/finally block.

[edit: I changed the sample to move `lock(sync)` earlier, to avoid the (unlikely) risk of a missed Pulse]

```
    static void Main()
    {
        object sync = new object();
        lock (sync)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Worker, sync);
            Console.WriteLine("Main sleeping");

            // wait for the worker to tell us it is ready
            Monitor.Wait(sync);
            Console.WriteLine("Main woke up!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void Worker(object sync)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Worker started; about to sleep");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Worker about pulse");
        lock (sync)
        { // notify Main that we did something interesting
            Monitor.Pulse(sync);
            Console.WriteLine("Worker pulsed; about to release lock");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Worker all done");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think the above will work, looks like you'll deadlock over sync

Comment: @Jan: Where exactly do you think it will deadlock? hint: it works fine

Comment: Or the explanation I added (to be fair, the explanation paragraph wasn't in the first version I posted)

Comment: Hahahaha, that's the exact mental process I went through when trying to figure out Monitor.Wait()/Monitor.Enter() code:

"Surely that's a deadlock"

The key piece of information is "the call to Wait releases the lock", which I didn't know.  Thanks Marc!

Comment: @endian : no problem. The bit I struggled with for a while is that it isn't Pulse() that re-starts Main, but when Worker *releases* the lock. Main still has to re-aquire the lock before it can continue.

Answer (score 3):

See if [this part of my threading article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml) helps... (the second half of that page). It implements a producer/consumer queue: when the producer produces something in the queue (and finds it was empty - as an optimisation), it pulses the monitor to wake up any waiting threads. When a consumer tries to consume from the queue but finds it empty, it waits for a pulse before trying again.

Alternatively, [Joe Albahari's threading tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_and_Pulse) has a section on Wait/Pulse too.

It's quite similar to the WaitHandle stuff you're used to - although frankly I find it easier to get my head round than WaitHandles, mostly because it's so similar to the Java wait/notify that I "grew up" with :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I had tried to figure it out from your fantastic site in the past, without success (and probably without enough effort).

Comment: In that case I'm *very* interested to hear about how I could improve the existing explanation :) To be honest it's been a while since I've done anything with the threading stuff - it could do with an overhaul. Any particular bits of the Wait/Pulse explanation which were confusing?